# Set CSV as default import into a spreadsheet

Tags: linux-mint, openoffice, csv, libreoffice

In Libreoffice I can import a CSV file into a spreadsheet by simply double-clicking on the text file.

In Openoffice 4.0 I have to click once on the text file to select it, then in the file type selector I have to go down and find the CSV option, select it, and then click on open.  In Libreoffice, CSV is obviously the default selection.

Is there a way in Openoffice to make CSV the default option?

Comment: Can't you configure the default application of opening `.csv` files to be OpenOffice Calc? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename the text file you want to import into OpenOffice Calc to something.csv.  Then, in calc select File > Open > and select the something.csv file from the list by double-clicking on it and the window with the options will appear.  Select the delimiter that the text file has that seperates the fields and then select "Open".